# Camunda, Modeler: "A JavaScript error occurred in the main process,... version `GLIBC_2.29' not found"

Tags: ubuntu, camunda, camunda-modeler

When I try to run **Camunda Modeler in Ubuntu**, I get the following error:

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Failed to load /opt/camunda-modeler/resources/app.asar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/electron-v12.0-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.hoRe47)
at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:1846)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:18)
at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:2073)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:935:32)
at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:14)
at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/camunda-modeler/resources/app.asar/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:32:13)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1078:30)
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
```

My system is updated and I already have Google Chrome installed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Based on https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc-dev-bin it looks like newer Camunda Modeller versions effectively require Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or newer - the GLIBC they are compiled for is newer than the one in 18.04

Answer (score 5):

Your Ubuntu GLIBC version seems outdated.

Try:

```
ldd --version
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

(newest version here for me is 2.31-0ubuntu9.2)

As a workaround you could fall back to an older modeler version as mentioned in one of the comments: https://downloads.camunda.cloud/release/camunda-modeler/4.8.1/camunda-modeler-4.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz

Comment: I already have `libc6` installed, but only Camunda 4.8 works. The latest version, not. Thanks for the downgrade tip.

Comment: what does ldd --version return? The error  indicates that the version is too low. Please upvote if it helped +  accept if it solved